# LinearLayout expanding when adding TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding `TextView` into a `LinearLayout` but this `LinearLayout` expands when I fill it with text (`TextView`). It's not an option to change it to `RelativeLayout` or something like that because I'm follow a guide from a book. This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ofcourse because parent with wrap_content will adjust to it's child width (largest among its child).

Comment: What are you seeing is the normal behaviour of a view-group (like Linearlayout). But what is your question ? Do you want a different behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you want it to do, but try changing the layout_width of the TextView and the LinearLayout it is in to "match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

When you add text to TextView width of that TextView is expanding as text gets bigger and width is set to "wrap_content" so its width is width of the text it holds. As a result LinearLayout which is parent view of that TextView gets bigger width since it's set to "wrap_content". And as a result of that ScrollView gets bigger and because of that outer LinearLayout gets bigger.

Solution to this would be to set LinearLayout width to "match_parent" or some arbitrary width("50dp" for example). In case of setting "match_parent" LinearLayout width would be width of the screen but you'll have to set "match_parent" to both LinearLayouts and ScrollView.

I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in xml file where you are specifying height to TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <!--Change your textView as below-->
            <TextView
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="60">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```